# User profile JSON data from SAP CP CF environment

Tags: java, s4sdk

Environment: Cloud Foundry Trail

I deployed my business & approuter applications using [help](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/07/18/step-7-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-secure-your-application-on-sap-cloud-platform-cloudfoundry/)

Now my requirement is get below `user profile` after `XSUAA` login.

Is there any `API` to get `user profile` details?

```
{
   "lastName": "XXXXX",
   "passwordStatus": "enabled",
   "mail": "XXXXX@gmail.com",
   "displayName": "XXXX XXXX XXXXX",
   "uid": "XXXXXX",
   "photoUrl": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/760fcd379cf60090e1e27b052f9e49bd?d=mm",
   "firstName": "XXXX",
   "contactPreferenceEmail": "unknown",
   "status": "active",
   "spUsersAttributes": [
      {
         "ServiceProviderName": "sapcpcf",
         "NameID": "XXXXX",
         "Status": "ACTIVE",
         "ActivationTime": "20181026050006Z"
      }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer:**

The IdP used by default on Cloud Foundry does not use SAML. Thus, mapping of SAML attributes does not work. Use the approach listed below only when using an IdP that supports SAML.

Instead, when using the default IdP, there three fields (`given_name`, `family_name`, `email`), that can be accessed as follows:

```
AuthTokenAccessor.getCurrentToken().get().getJwt().getClaim("email").asString();
```

**Original answer:**

you can do the following:

First, add a role template to your `xs-security.json` you used to configure your XSUAA instance like this:

```
{
    "name": "Authenticated",
    "description": "All authenticated users",
    "attribute-references": [ 
        "given_name", 
        "family_name",
        "email"
    ]
}
```

Note that you need to recreate the XSUAA instance with the new config in order for this change to work.

Now, in the roles section of your Identity Provider (if you use the default Cloud Foundry IdP you can find that under the "Security" tab on the left of the Cloud Cockpit), you can configure how these fields should be filled. Choose "Identity Provider" there.

Of course make sure that this role is assigned to every user.

Finally, you read the information using the `UserAccessor`:

```
final User currentUser = UserAccessor.getCurrentUser();

currentUser.getAttribute("email");
```

This should help you get the necessary information!

Comment: I recreated XSUAA service with `attributes` using [help](https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/150b04d647cd4b42835411c1787a8b11.html)
I didn't find `Identity Provider` under `Security` tab.
In `NEO` environment I am able to get `com.sap.security.um.user.User` object using 
`InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
UserProvider userProvider = (UserProvider) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/user/Provider");
User userProfile = userProvider.getUser(userName);`
Please suggest me to get `userprofile` with groups & etc. in CF environment

Comment: When you're in the Cloud Cockpit, you first need to navigate down to application level (remember Global Account > Subaccount > Space > Application). Only then you will in the sidebar on the left see the tab "Roles" under "Security". There you can edit your roles and perform the configuration described above.

Comment: I created Role with above attributes, and created role i assigned to my testing user  email id, but values showing empty. please suggest me what i missed.

Comment: Getting attribute values empty like 'email=CollectionUserAttribute(name=email, values=[])' from ScpCfUser. Please suggest me how to resolve?

Comment: Hi Dennis! Thank you very much for your reply!

I can get email, given_name, family_name, ect with your approach

But I am unable to get uid: PXXXX, groups.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no dedicated API to get all of these user profile details. You can use the `AuthTokenAccessor` to access the current JWT which should contain this information.